# TypeError: Cannot set property '_bitField' of undefined (Bluebird library)

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using bluebird 2.x.

I am making a call to kafka which is wrapped inside a promise. The promise is resolved if the message is published. The promis is rejected if the call to kafka fails.

Here is the piece of code that is causing the error -

```
redis.get(something)
.then(function() { 
            return Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // This is Line 98 in the stacktrace
                producer.send([
                    {
                        topic : "Ganga",
                        messages : [JSON.stringify({// some object})]
                    }
                ], function(err, data) {
                    if(err) {
                        logger.error("Error")
                        logger.error(err);
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve(data);
                })
            });
        })
```

The stacktrace is as follows

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '_bitField' of undefined
    at <project base path>/index.js:98:20
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:293:12)
    at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)
From previous event:
    at Server.<anonymous> (<project base path>/index.js:97:10)
    at next (<project base path>/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:912:30)
    at f (<project base path>/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at Server.parseBody (<project base path>/node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/body_parser.js:94:13)
    at next (<project base path>/node_modules/restify/lib/server.js:912:30)
    at f (<project base path>/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at IncomingMessage.done (<project base path>/node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/body_reader.js:121:13)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Any suggestion on what could be wrong?

Comment: What's `producer.send`? Also please open an issue at the bluebird repo

Comment: You're missing `new` before `Promise`, but that's not the error I'd expect you to get.

Comment: Use new before Promise. I faced the same error last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Thrown on line 98 its definitely due to not using new before Promise.